# 64 bit Ubuntu for HP Proliant DL160 G6 Server?

Tags: 64-bit

Does this [32 bit Ubuntu download](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/200907-3393/) mean that I can install only 32 bit Ubuntu on my HP Proliant DL160 G6 which has the Intel Xeon L5520 processor that handles both 64/32bit ? I would like to take advantage of the 64bit processing power.

Do I have to settle for this 32bit Ubuntu or has anyone been successful in running any other 64bit versions for Proliant DL160/Intel Xeon L5520 ?

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: No you can install the 64bit.